# React native UI Kitten causes slow start up

Tags: react-native, performance, react-native-ui-kitten, cold-start

I noticed that when The ApplicationProvider tag is present, my react native app start up time increases to more than 5 seconds. I've already followed the guide from UI-Kitten team by improving the performance through configuring the metro.config.js file but doesn't seem to help.

```
<ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{...eva.light, ...theme}}>
       <Text>{'Test'}</Text>
</ApplicationProvider>
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% sure the startup time is caused by KittenUI can your try to run

```
npx react-native-bundle-visualizer --expo managed
```

You will have an output with a nice image to help you identify your bundle size